# Is it possible to wrap the rootViewController within another ViewController?

Tags: ios, slide

Right now I'm attempting to integrate [this library](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) with an existing app. However, the app already has a rootViewController. Is it possible to simply redirect the frontView this library requires to the current rootViewController that the app has? All I need to implement is the ability to swipe between the rearViewController and the frontViewController like in the first example the library gives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but then you need to set the SWRevealController as the new rootViewController.

Here's some sample code to illustrate from `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` in your app delegate:

```
MYAppViewController *mainVC = [[MYAppViewController alloc] init];

// Before using SWRevealViewController I had this line:
// self.window.rootViewController = mainVC

// Used for the rear view of the SWRevealViewController    
MYMenuViewController *menuVC = [[MYMenuViewController alloc] init];

SWRevealViewController *revealVC = [[SWRevealViewController alloc] initWithRearViewController:menuVC frontViewController:mainVC];

// Now set the SWRevealViewController as the root view controller
self.window.rootViewController = revealVC;
```

Comment: If the old rootViewController was the home page of the app, what happens to the home page? Does it  change because I changed what the rootViewController is to frontViewController? Is there a way to link frontViewController to the previous rootViewController to maintain the same home page? Or am I just thinking about this wrong? (very possible as I'm an iOS programming noob).

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you mean, but probably the easiest way is to just try it out and see what happens. If you set the 'home page' to the frontView of the reveal controller, and set the reveal controller as the root view controller, then the app will look exactly the same on launch (except you now have the ability to swipe to reveal the back view). If you're still stuck, post the code you have tried and we might be able to help further.

Comment: Hey James, your advice worked great! Got it implemented with very few issues :)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Just make your `rootViewController` class inherit from `SWRevealViewController`, then you wont need to wrap anything.</strike>

read the [Documentation](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController#usage) it explains what to do. You don't need to wrap anything.

Comment: I'm pretty fresh when it comes to iOS, so I don't quite understand what I would do to make that happen :/

Could you give a small example?

Comment: I can't say I completely understand what usage is asking me to do - I definitely know how to do the first couple steps, but after that the language is foreign to me. 

I'd really appreciate if you could break it down into Layman's terms! :)